# Where Clause Order Performance, Limit Index Usage

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to run a query on a table with 125 million rows. The data is stored with a date and I'm trying to select data by a month at a time. I'm using a query like:

```
select id from stats where page regexp '...'  and timestamp between '2020-04-12' and '2020-05-12'
```

an explain shows:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys             | key       | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stats | range | timestamp_video,timestamp | timestamp | 4       | NULL | 10257708 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

the rows being examined here seem to high to me:

```
select count(*) from stats where timestamp between '2020-04-12' and '2020-05-12';
```

returns:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  4840392 |
+----------+
```

DB structure:

```
`page` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` date DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `timestamp_video` (`timestamp`,`video`),
KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
```

The `page` column has entries with with +1000 characters. The `timestamp_video` index isn't needed, so is there a way to tell MySQL to ignore that index and just use the single `timestamp` index?

Maybe there a way to rewrite this using a subquery so rows meeting the timestamp are returned then rows matching the regex?

Query currently takes over 19516 seconds to execute. Trying to get that to under 600.

**Update**

Regex example,

it can be +12000 characters long (string in question was `12077`) and looks like:

```
access=()
```

inside the parentheses there are varying 10 character long alphanumeric strings separated by `|`.

partial complete example:

```
page regexp 'access=(3slaug6h82|5qew9gd4tn|o7vr3e9tix|5coakhoymq|1axg2vf8qt|7uh9ptld4v|vpgaix9wm8|0klcvjbrm8|x19ozupcre|fo2tjd7cxn)'
```

A sample value `page` could contain would be:

```
www.example.com/page?param1=true&access=3slaug6h82&param3=false&user=1234
```

Comment: It's actually using the `timestamp` index, as you see in the `KEY` column of the plan. Now, you are still reading and processing 5 million rows. That's going to take some time.

Comment: It's going through twice as many rows though. Is it doing it once for the timestamp then a second iteration for the regexp?

Comment: That's true. It uses the `timestamp` index for the dates, then it reads the main index for the regexp. That's where a single index with both columns could help, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @user3783243 - No.  The "Rows" in `EXPLAIN` is an estimate.  This time the estimate is 2x bigger than reality.

Comment: Let's see a typical regexp string; perhaps `FULLTEXT` is what you need.

Comment: @RickJames I've added more details about regex. If anything else is needed please let me know.

Comment: Are the "words" in `page` separated by spaces or punctuation?  Is there a problem with what might happen after the regexp?  For example `REGEXP access=(a|b)` will match `...access=ax...`  Would `FULLTEXT` apply?

Comment: @RickJames There are no spaces, `page` is a URL. It can be very long if a proxy server was used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FULLTEXT(page)`:

```
SELECT ft FROM `desc_bug` 
    WHERE MATCH(ft) AGAINST('5qew9gd4tn|3slaug6h82|asdfasdfd' IN BOOLEAN MODE)\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
ft: www.example.com/page?param1=true&access=3slaug6h82&param3=false&user=1234
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note:  This checks only the odd "word"; you could add the the regexp to verify that it has `access=` in front of it:

```
    AND ft REGEXP 'access=(...)'
```

Since it should use the FT index first, it should be a lot faster than your original attempt.

Comment: Rick, I'm going to be testing this out shortly. Adding the `fulltext` index locks my table for +8 hours. I've built a duplicate copy and am moving the data over.

Comment: @user3783243 - 8 hours to do `ADD FULLTEXT(page)`.  Sorry; 125M rows will take time.  Is it InnoDB?

Comment: Yes, it is using `innodb`; From `show create table`, `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=173776304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`